# Contenteditable bug in chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, contenteditable, clearfix

I'm using Chrome 27.0.1453.93 and Ubuntu 13.04

If we have `contenteditable="true"` on element with `float` set to `left` or `right`, and if the parent of this element has `clearfix` class, we can see strange behaviour, when content becomes editable after clickng anywhere - http://jsfiddle.net/sApBk/2/.

Bug only exists in Chrome, but when viewed in FF and Opera, everything is ok.

Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: i suggest you to report bug Chrome_menu->Tools->Report bug